What software can we use to plot magnetically induced currents in aromatic compounds?
I am investigating some polyaromatic compounds, and I wish to plot the ring currents to gain further insights into their aromaticity. Is there any software (other than AICD) that may be employed to do the same?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Have you looked into GIMIC?
https://gimic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
It is free and designed to perform calculations based on the output of various programs (Turbomole, Gaussian, CFOUR) and methods. GIMIC can be used to compute magnetically induced ring currents along chemical bonds, visualize magnetically induced ring current densities, and create spaghetti plots to explore ring current pathways.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
